# ASP.NET Problem with Redirects

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have a login page which has two options "login as guest" , "login".  Each click event will take the user to the same page.  However, if login as guest is clicked then i want to be able to change what info is displayed on the page the user is being redirected to.  I do not want to use a session variable.  Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a querystring variable in the link. E.g.,

```
http://www.MySite.com/MyPage.aspx?login=guest
```